# TIKZ: description below mirrored brace

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, braces

I use tikz to make some diagrams and also braces. Now i had to mirror a brace, but the description of the brace is now above the brace - not anymore below. I tried to make a separate node for this text, but it's failed.

Here is my latex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mynode/.style={font=\footnotesize, align=center, minimum height=1.1cm}]
\node[mynode, draw] (text1) {text};
\node[mynode, draw, right=-\pgflinewidth of text1] (text2) {Even more test};
\node[mynode, draw, right=-\pgflinewidth of text2] (text3) {\hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx}Teeeeeext \hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx}};
\node[mynode, below left=-0.3cm and -0.5cm of text1] (dummy_links) {};
\node[mynode, below right=-0.3cm and -0.4cm of text3] (dummy_rechts) {};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(dummy_links.south west) -- (dummy_rechts.south east) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Yeah, maybe confusing, but thats how it is).

This is how it looks:
[image]

But it should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `xshift` to `yshift`.

[image: brace]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mynode/.style={font=\footnotesize, align=center, minimum height=1.1cm}]
\node[mynode, draw] (text1) {text};
\node[mynode, draw, right=-\pgflinewidth of text1] (text2) {Even more test};
\node[mynode, draw, right=-\pgflinewidth of text2] (text3) {\hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx}Teeeeeext \hphantom{xxxxxxxxxx}};
\node[mynode, below left=-0.3cm and -0.5cm of text1] (dummy_links) {};
\node[mynode, below right=-0.3cm and -0.4cm of text3] (dummy_rechts) {};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(dummy_links.south west) -- (dummy_rechts.south east) node [black,midway,yshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: great, that works. Didn't thought about that.